# SP13 Blog - Group Permissions - Limited to comment

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

I want to create a user group with the following permissions:

- Comment on a post
- Like a post
- Reply to a post

I don't wish them to be able to:

- Edit a page
- Add web parts
- delete content

Please, can you direct me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom permissions level or can use exiting "Contribute" permissions for this.

1. Create a users group and add respective users in it
2. Grant that group Read-Only permissions on whole Blog Site
3. Go to Comments list permissions and Stop Permissions Inheritance in Blog Site
4. Grant the users group you created in Step 1 as contribute permissions

So now that newly created users group has Read-Only permissions across the site except the Comments section and that should resolve your problem.

Hope that helps.